# Show that the line through $P$ and $Q$ is perpendicular to the surface at $P$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, linear-approximation

Consider a smooth surface given by the function $z = f(x,y)$, such that the partial
derivatives of $f(x,y)$ exist. Suppose $Q$ is a point that does not lie on the surface,
and $P$ is the nearest point on the surface to $Q$. Show that the line through $P$ and
$Q$ is perpendicular to the surface at $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$. For any point $S=(x,y,f(x,y))$ on the surface define the function

$$g(x,y)=(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2+(f(x,y)-\gamma)^2$$

The function $g(x,y)$ represents the square of the distance between $S$ and $Q$.

Let $P=(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0)$ denote the nearest point the surface $Q$.

Then $g(x_0,y_0)$ is the minimum value of $g(x,y)$.

Now $$g_x(x,y)=2(x-\alpha)+2(f(x,y)-\gamma)f_x(x,y)$$
$$g_y(x,y)=2(y-\beta)+2(f(x,y)-\gamma)f_y(x,y)$$

so $$0=2(x_0-\alpha)+2(f(x_0,y_0)-\gamma)f_x(x_0,y_0) \tag{1}$$
$$0=2(y_0-\beta)+2(f(x_0,y_0)-\gamma)f_y(x_0,y_0) \tag{2}$$

The equation of the tangent plane at $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by
$$z=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

which is standard scalar form $ax+by+cz=d$, is expressed as
$$f_x(x_0,y_0)x+f_y(x_0,y_0)y-z=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

From the above equation a normal vector for the plane is read off as being
$$n=(f_x(x_0,y_0), f_y(x_0,y_0), -1)$$

Now, $$\overrightarrow{QP}=(x_0-\alpha,y_0-\beta,f(x_0,y_0)-\gamma)$$
$$\overrightarrow{QP}=(\gamma-f(x_0,y_0))(f_x(x_0,y_0), f_y(x_0,y_0), -1)$$
$$\overrightarrow{QP}=(\gamma-f(x_0,y_0))n$$

Where $equation (1)(2)$ have been used in going from the first line to the second. Sice $Q$ does not lie on the surface, $(\gamma-f(x_0,y_0))\neq0$. It follows that $n$ and $\overrightarrow{QP}$ are parallel, so the line through $P$ and $Q$ is perpendicular to the surface at $P$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is incorrect I am afraid. $Q$ also must be at a minimum distance to   the surface.

The required normal direction comes from cross-product $ \partial z / \partial x$ **X** $   \partial z / \partial y $

Comment: This question is from a exercise of the text book, So I assume its correct maybe.

Comment: Textbooks are not always correct. $PQ$ should be common normal.

Comment: Ok maybe its a wrong question, anyways I was wondering if we could find a tangent line using partial derivative then we can find a normal line, which would be perpendicular to the tangent line. If that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, but how is the question incorrect? “... $P$ is the nearest point on the surface to $Q$” says to me that the distance is minimal.

Comment: @amd do you know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Reboot That depends on what you’re allowed to use. The first, and likely easiest, thing that comes to my mind is to set this up as a constrained minimization problem to be solved via a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: @amd here is the solution from my professor.